# Python3.5.1: Appending to a list from a list doesn't work

Tags: list, append, python-3.5

What I'm trying to do is to have my python code read a .txt -file with ";" separated values on each line, then separate each value on each line to a list, and finally append these values to a assigned lists.

Here's what I've tried...

```
pullData= open("example.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8').read()
dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
array_one = []
array_two = []

for eachLine in dataArray:
    lineArray = eachLine.split(';')
    array_one.append(lineArray[0])
    array_two.append(lineArray[1])
```

This example results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPath.py", line 25, in <module>
    array_two.append(lineArray[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The splitting of each line works as it should as printing these lists works just fine; i.e.:

```
for eachLine in dataArray:
        lineArray = eachLine.split(';')
        print(lineArray[0])
        print(lineArray[1])
```

...as the above returns what it should.

```
>>> 
RESTART: MyPath.py 
Jeff
1009

Bill
771
```

Any ideas on what the problem could be here...?

P.S. The data (i.e. "example.txt") is something like this:

```
Jeff;1009;3486;24047
Bill;771;371;3867
Michael;931;2131;3331
Jess;3311;9761;3886
Cathy;571;1301;63668
```

Comment: Evidently not all of your data is long enough

Comment: Sorry but you're using some other file there, possibly with an extra newline at the end.

Comment: Do you mean missing values within lines or that some of the "lines" in the .txt-file don't include enough to split by? Because I double-checked some first 50 lines of the file, and did a test run on that, and it still failed... :/

Comment: Yes, the latter code should fail exactly the same way than the former; i.e. "The splitting of each line works as it should as printing these lists works just fine" cannot be true.

Comment: Oh man!!! I can't believe how dum I was! :D
I did my "test" with the double-checked 50 sample, but failed to realize that my editor added the extra line at the bottom regardless since I just pasted it to another editor window. So there you have it, now it's working... Thank you Antti Haapala! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an you have an empty newline at the end of the file. Try:

```
for eachLine in dataArray:
    lineArray = eachLine.split(';')
    if len(lineArray) >= 2:
        array_one.append(lineArray[0])
        array_two.append(lineArray[1])
```

Comment: Cheers! You were right, it was an extra line at the bottom, even though I tried to be careful.. :D But your line " if len(lineArray) >= 2:" worked perfectly! Thank you so much!